# I need help fixing my code - very fragile

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and for my assignment I have to program a simple `'Higher or Lower'` style game.

I'm currently trying to make it so the user can't crash the game by entering an invalid input, but I'm stuck at the point where it asks the user to decide how much money they want to start with.

I tried a few things but I mostly always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Liam/Desktop/game test 2-6-6.py", line 36, in <module>
    print("\nBank Account: £", LTDbank_account)
NameError: name 'LTDbank_account' is not defined
```

Trying to learn as much as I can so any help to fix this or anything else in my code would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I should also mention this is on Python 3.4.3 if that matters

```
import random

highlow = True

while highlow == True:
    LTDplay = input("Would you like to play Higher or Lower? [ y | n ] ")
    if LTDplay == "y" or LTDplay == "n":
        highlow = False
    else:
        print("invalid entry")

    print("-"*40)                               

while LTDplay == "n":                       
    quit()

LTDscore = 0
LTDtries = 0
LTDwagered = 0              
LTDwon = 0
LTDwin_rate = 0

while LTDplay == "y":

    try:
        LTDbank_account = int(input("Please enter the amount of money you wish to start with: £"))
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid entry")

    LTDdie1 = random.randint(1,10)
    print("\n| Die 1: ", LTDdie1)
    print("\nBank Account: £", LTDbank_account)

    LTDbet = int(input("\nPlease place your bet: £"))
    LTDwagered = LTDwagered + LTDbet    
    LTDwinnings = LTDbet/2              
    LTDguess = input("\nDo you think the next number will be Higher or Lower? [ h | l ] ") 

    print("\nPlease wait while I roll the dice")

    print ("-"*20)

    import time             
    time.sleep(2)

    LTDdie2 = random.randint(1,10)      
    print("\n| Die 2: ", LTDdie2)       

    if LTDguess == "h":                 
        if LTDdie2 > LTDdie1:
            print("\n*** Congratulations You Win! ***")         
            LTDbank_account = LTDbank_account + LTDwinnings
            LTDwon = LTDwon + LTDwinnings
            LTDscore = LTDscore + 1        
            LTDtries = LTDtries + 1
            print("\nScore: ", LTDscore)
            print("-"*40)
        elif LTDdie2 < LTDdie1:
            print("\n*** Sorry You Lose ***")               
            LTDbank_account = LTDbank_account - LTDbet
            LTDtries = LTDtries + 1
            print("\nScore: ", LTDscore)
            print("-"*40)
        elif LTDdie2 == LTDdie1:
            print("\n*** It's a Draw! ***")                 
            LTDtries = LTDtries + 1
            print("\nScore: ", LTDscore)
            print("-"*40)

    if LTDguess == "l":                 
        if LTDdie2 > LTDdie1:
            print("\n*** Sorry You Lose! ***")
            LTDbank_account = LTDbank_account - LTDbet
            LTDtries = LTDtries + 1
            print("\nScore: ", LTDscore)
            print("-"*40)
        elif LTDdie2 < LTDdie1:
            print("\n*** Congratulations You Win! ***")
            LTDscore = LTDscore + 1
            LTDtries = LTDtries + 1
            LTDbank_account = LTDbank_account + LTDwinnings
            LTDwon = LTDwon + LTDwinnings
            print("\nScore: ", LTDscore)
            print("-"*40)
        elif LTDdie2 == LTDdie1:
            print("\n*** It's a Draw! ***") 
            LTDtries = LTDtries + 1
            print("\nScore: ", LTDscore)
            print("-"*40)

    LTDwin_rate = (LTDscore / LTDtries)*100         

    if LTDbank_account <= 0:
        print("\nLooks like you're all out of money!\n\n*** GAME OVER ***")
        print("\n| Tries: ", LTDtries)
        print("\n| Score: ", LTDscore)
        print("\n| Win Rate(%): ", LTDwin_rate)
        print("\n| Wagered: £", LTDwagered)
        print("\n| Winnings: £", LTDwon)

    LTDplay = input("\nDo you want to play again? [ y | n ] ")
    while LTDplay == "n":
        print("-"*40)
        print("\n FINAL STATS")
        print("\n| Tries: ", LTDtries)
        print("\n| Score: ", LTDscore)
        print("\n| Win Rate(%): ", LTDwin_rate)
        print("\n| Wagered: £", LTDwagered)
        print("\n| Winnings: £", LTDwon)

        time.sleep(7)      
        quit()
```

Comment: What is the value of `LTDbank_account` when exception occurs?

Comment: are you seeing "invalid entry" in your output? if you're trying to enter a money amount and it isn't purely integral in value, you'll get an exception in the int() call and pop out of the try/except and never set the value of LTDbank_account.

Comment: Also, consider dealing with when value of `LTDguess` does not equal `h` or `l`.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski it's only when the user enters something that isn't a number that it has the error.

Comment: @mrogers Yeah I want to eventually do this for all input options

Comment: Interested, why you used `while` instead of `if` ? 

`while LTDplay == "n":                       
    quit()`

We usually use `if LTDplay == "n": quit()`

Comment: You can probably consider making your program more modular, moving separate pieces into functions, named accordingly to what happens inside. This will make the code more expressive and flexible.

Comment: @IvanGeorgiev That's because I don't really know what I'm doing haha, like I said I'm very new to this and relying on the notes i've made in class.

Comment: Have in mind how the functions you are using really work. For example `int(input("Please enter the amount of money you wish to start with: £"))` will always fail if the user follows your instructions to add the pound symbol. `123` is a valid integer and the `int("123")` will produce integer number `123`, while `int("£123")` will fail, because `£123` is not a valid number.

Comment: @Liam next time, use a meaningful title for your question. `I need help fixing my code - very fragile` is not informative at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first entry is invalid, you print the appropriate message, but then you continue the game with no value.  That would cause the problem you see.

Instead, you need a loop to get a valid value, something more like

```
okay = False
while not okay:
    try:
        LTDbank_account = int(input("Please enter ..."))
        okay = True
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid entry")
```

*After* you satisfy this loop, you can continue with the rest of the program.

```
LTDdie1 = random.randint(1,10)
print("\n| Die 1: ", LTDdie1)
print("\nBank Account: £", LTDbank_account)   # Apparent crash point
...
```

Comment: Glad it helped.  Remember to up-vote useful things and accept one answer (you got another one about the same time, also quite useful), so this question gets properly archived.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, if the user inputs something invalid, a message is printed but then the code continues regardless, with `LTDbank_account` undefined. Instead,  try looping around your `input` statement *until* you've got a valid value for `LTDbank_account`:

```
while True:
    try:
        LTDbank_account = int(input("Please enter the amount of money you wish to start with: £"))
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid entry")
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

What's likely happening is that you're hitting an exception on the line:

```
LTDbank_account = int(input("Please enter the amount of money you wish to start with: £"))
```

If this is true, you'll see the text from the `except` block printed the console before your error traceback, specifically:

> invalid input

What you probably want is for the user to be prompted again for an amount until he gives a valid value.  You could wrap your original try/except block in a while loop and break from it once the input is valid like so:

```
while True:
    try:
        LTDbank_account = int(input("Please enter the amount of money you wish to start with: £"))
        break
    except:
        print("invalid entry")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the user enter valid input before proceeding. Here is an example:

```py
try:
    LTDbank_account = int(input("Please enter the amount of money you wish to start with: £"))
except ValueError:
    print("invalid entry")
```

This will continue the execution no matter the user entered invalid input. One way to fix this is to use open (unconditional) loop. Another point here is that if the user starts the entry with `£`, it will never convert to integer. I changed your prompt:

```py
# Input loop. Continue until valid input.
while True:
    try:
        LTDbank_account = int(input("Please enter the amount of money as integer number:"))
        break     # Vaild entry. Break the input loop
    except ValueError:
        print("Seems you didn't enter valid money amount. Please try again.")
```

I didn't check all the places which need amendment. Go through you code carefully and think what will happen. Then change it.

Comment: Habit. Thank you, Peter.